# Get name of created file

Tags: python

I'm creating files in python and I want to print the full path of the already file created. Example:

```
dt = datetime.datetime.now()
datetime = dt.strftime("%d-%m")
output = open("c:\path\to\file_"+datetime+".txt","w")
```

How can I print the final name of the created file?

I tried:

```
print (output)
```

but it gives me a rare string.

Comment: Please consider opening the file using `with`, so that it is closed when you no longer need it.

Comment: Do not assign a value to a package name. `datetime` is the name of the package you install: `import datetime` by doing `datetime = dt.strftime("%d-%m")` you are re-assigning the variable `datetime` and will not be able to use `datetime.datetime.now()` anywhere later in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For real file objects such as that,

```
print(output.name)
```

Comment: Another (stupider) option is to store the filename in a variable before creating it!

Answer (score 0):

open() method doesn't return anything relevant. You can try on below methods...

```
1.print(output.__file__)


2. Import os
     os.path.abspath("filename.ext"). # it will add the cwd to file name or if iterating the real path
    os.path.dirname("filename.ext")
    os.path.dirname("filename.ext") 

3. Files= os.listdir(os.getcwd()) # it will list the files in cwd(you can give any path)
    for i in files:
        print(os.path.abspath(i))
```